# Why does Series.resampleUniform return an empty series?

Tags: f#, time-series, deedle

I cannot understand why `resmplU` in the code below is an empty series.

I suspect the problem is I do not understand the role of the parameter `nextKey` in the signature of `resampleUniform`. The help says it "is used to generate all keys in the range," but I could not figure out what that means.

```
open Deedle
let dateRange skip (startDate: System.DateTime) endDate =
    Seq.initInfinite float
    |> Seq.map (fun i -> startDate.AddDays (skip * i))
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun dt -> dt <= endDate)

let dt3 = DateTime(2017,4,1)    
let dt4 = DateTime(2017,4,30)
let dt5 = DateTime(2017,4,15)

let dateR = dateRange 2.0 dt3 dt4
let valsR = [1..dateR |> Seq.length]
let tseries = Series(dateR, valsR)
let resmplU =
    tseries
    |> Series.resampleUniform Lookup.ExactOrGreater (fun x -> x < dt5) id
```

After running this code I get:

```
val dt3 : DateTime = 4/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
val dt4 : DateTime = 4/30/2017 12:00:00 AM
val dt5 : DateTime = 4/15/2017 12:00:00 AM
val dateR : seq<DateTime>
val valsR : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15]
val tseries : Series<DateTime,int> =
  series [ 4/1/2017 12:00:00 AM => 1; 4/3/2017 12:00:00 AM => 2; 4/5/2017 12:00:00 AM => 3; 4/7/2017 12:00:00 AM => 4; 4/9/2017 12:00:00 AM => 5;  ... ; 4/29/2017 12:00:00 AM => 15]
val resmplU : Series<bool,Series<DateTime,int>> = series [ ]
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Series.resampleUniform` function lets you rescale values in a series to a new set of keys. For example, given your series:

```
01/04/2017 -> 1  
03/04/2017 -> 2  
05/04/2017 -> 3  
07/04/2017 -> 4  
09/04/2017 -> 5  
11/04/2017 -> 6  
13/04/2017 -> 7  
15/04/2017 -> 8  
17/04/2017 -> 9  
19/04/2017 -> 10 
21/04/2017 -> 11 
23/04/2017 -> 12 
25/04/2017 -> 13 
27/04/2017 -> 14 
29/04/2017 -> 15
```

You can resample the series so that the keys are days in the month from 1 to 29. For each key (day), you will get values on that specific day, or values on the next day for which they are available:

```
tseries
|> Series.resampleUniform Lookup.ExactOrGreater (fun dt -> dt.Day) (fun d -> d + 1)
```

The first function `dt -> dt.Day` turns keys from the original series into keys in the new series (to illustrate how this works, I'm using `int` as keys for the returned series) and the second function `d -> d + 1` calculates the next key of the target series.

**EDIT** I think the problem with your idea of using `bool` as the key is that the resampling function needs to calculate one more key *after* the two keys in the series you want to get - so that it can make sure it reached the end. This does not work for `bool` as there are only two values. The following works though:

```
tseries
|> Series.resampleUniform Lookup.ExactOrGreater 
       (fun x -> if x < dt5 then 0 else 1) (fun n -> n + 1)
```

Comment: Ok, I understand it better now. And I see that I made a mistake in using `id` as the `nextKey` argument . But it would seem to me that the example code should work with `not` replacing `id`, as the function `not` should calculate the next boolean key. If that were the case I should get a series with two keys, true and false. But I get an empty series. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `not` calculates the next key but does not establish a transitive relation (ordering) in the `bool` type.